# Python: write to module internal files

Tags: python-3.x, module

For Python modules it is possible to deploy non-coding files as part of a package. In order to access the data from the `__init__.py` I need to use for example:

```
import pkgutil

data = pkgutil.get_data("myproject", "resources/cities.txt")
```

So far so good. However, how can the `__init__.py` write to those non-coding files? As far as I know, there is no possibility to use `pkgutil` in this case.